# How to find out when to use mein or meine?

Tags: difference

I need to know to find when to attach an e to the end of mein(e). I have learnt that the *e* goes on the end because of masculine and feminine, but struggle to know how to find the feminine/masculine in a word.

Comment: It's not only in case of masculine/feminine but also for singular/pural.

Comment: Tell me more please.

Comment: I don't understand the "how to find the feminine/ masculine in a word" part of your question. You may want to clarify that. The declension table for _mein_ can be found at http://www.canoo.net/inflection/mein:Pron:Poss:1st:SG.

Comment: @johnl There's no fixed rule to do that at all. That's probably why this question is currently receiving close votes as being _too broad_. I'll try to give a concise answer now though.

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein

Comment: @GermanLearner In case this is unclear to you: each noun in german has a gender associated to it, which you have to learn together with the word. And additional to feminine/masculine there is also a neuter gender.

Comment: *meine* is if the thing which is *yours* plural, or feminine. To be able to determinate the gender of a word, theoretically you have to learn it with the word. In practice it doesn't work, because your brain isn't wired on this way. Mixing the gender is bad mistake, although the native speakers already accustomed it. Nothing helps, except you are fighting hardly and long, slowly it will find its way. Try to think on the words as if they would have a gender.

Answer (score 2):

As usage of *mein* or *meine* actually as a possessive pronoun depends on the subject being either

- masculine (no *e* appended) or feminine (*e* appended)
- singular (no *e* appended) or plural (*e* appended)

it depends on what the subject actually is. Determining the subjects gender or plurality is quite a broad field, and there's no regular rule we can really give you about that.

Here are some examples:

- > *Mein Kater* (masculine subject) vs *Meine Katze* (feminine subject), but
  >   *Mein Kater* (singular subject) vs *Meine Kater* (plural subject)
- > *Mein Sohn* (masculine subject) vs *Meine Tochter* (feminine subject), but
  >   *Mein Kind* (singular subject) vs *Meine Kinder* (plural subject)
- > *Mein Liebster* (masculine subject) vs *Meine Liebste* (feminine subject), but
  >   *Mein Liebster* (singular subject) vs *Meine Liebsten* (plural subject)
- > *Mein Ideal* (singular subject) vs *Meine Ideale* (plural subject)

Thus you see, you have to determine the gender or plurality of the subject word in first place (which isn't actually following regular rules in German, and you just need to memorize the irregularities) to decide, if you use *mein* or *meine* for each particular case.